# Trying to find the nearest date today in a <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the next/nearest date to today from a list of dates and then add a class to it and display that item in another place.

```
<ul class="locations">
    <li>
        <span class="date">01-Jun-2015</span> 
        <span class="location">London</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="date">15-Jun-2015</span> 
        <span class="location">Paris</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="date">03-Jul-2015</span> 
        <span class="location">Berlin</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="date">16-Jun-2015</span> 
        <span class="location">Milan</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="date">20-Jul-2015</span> 
        <span class="location">Madrid</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="date">07-Aug-2015</span> 
        <span class="location">Lisbon</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<p class="next-date">
    Next date and location: 
</p>
```

Please can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Nearest date to which date?

Comment: Convert each `span` inner text into Date. Then for each Date compare its "distance" to current Date and choose the smallest "distance". Add class to related `span`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you'd be okay with `jQuery` as your question is tagged so. You could find the **nearest future date to today** using a couple of in-built functions, such as [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) as below. Pls look at the comments in the script for more info about the code.

```js
var $locations = $(".locations");

//Today's date in milliseconds
var tsToday = new Date().getTime();

//Create an array of timestamps using .map
var allDatesTimestamp = $locations.find(".date").map(function() {
    //Convert text to date in milliseconds
    var ts = new Date($(this).text()).getTime();
    //Return only those timestamps that are greater than today
    //And sort them to get the smallest/nearest timestamp as the first array item
    if (ts > tsToday) {
        return ts;
    }
}).get().sort();

//Find all .date elements and filter out
var $elem = $locations.find(".date").filter(function() {
    //Filter out the one where date equals to first item in the array as that's the nearest
    return new Date($(this).text()).getTime() === allDatesTimestamp[0]
    //Return the sarrounding element
    //Add a class if need be, to highlight it
}).closest("li").addClass("nearest");

//Rest is simple; find and display.
$(".next-date")
.append("Date: " + $elem.find(".date").text())
.append("<br/>Location: " + $elem.find(".location").text());
```

```css
.locations .nearest {
    color: green;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="locations">
    <li>
        <span class="date">01-Jun-2015</span> 
        <span class="location">London</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="date">15-Jun-2015</span> 
        <span class="location">Paris</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="date">03-Jul-2015</span> 
        <span class="location">Berlin</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="date">16-Jun-2015</span> 
        <span class="location">Milan</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="date">20-Jul-2015</span> 
        <span class="location">Madrid</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="date">07-Aug-2015</span> 
        <span class="location">Lisbon</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<p class="next-date">
    <strong>Next date and location: </strong><br/>
</p>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this is my preferred method, thank you. Commenting has massively helped!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom sort function to sort the closet next date

```
  dates.sort(function(x, y) { 
    if (x[0]-Date.now() < 0) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (x[0]-Date.now() < y[0]-Date.now()) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (x[0]-Date.now() > y[0]-Date.now()) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kpqvxv

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Date()` for comparison:

```js
$(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime(); //get current time
  var li, diff, sp, tmp;
  $('span.date').each(function() {//loop in all dates
    sp = $(this);
    if (!li) {// first time
      li = sp.closest('li'); // get parent of date
      diff = Math.abs(now - new Date(sp.text()).getTime()); //get differnce
      return;
    }
    tmp = Math.abs(now - new Date(sp.text()).getTime());
    if (tmp < diff) { // this is close to current date
      diff = tmp;
      li = sp.closest('li'); 
    }
  });
  li.addClass('now'); // highlight
  $('p.next-date').text(function() {
 return this.innerHTML + li.text(); // update date and place
  });
});
```

```css
.now {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="locations">
  <li>
    <span class="date">01-Jun-2015</span> 
    <span class="location">London</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="date">15-Jun-2015</span> 
    <span class="location">Paris</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="date">03-Jul-2015</span> 
    <span class="location">Berlin</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="date">16-Jun-2015</span> 
    <span class="location">Milan</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="date">20-Jul-2015</span> 
    <span class="location">Madrid</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="date">07-Aug-2015</span> 
    <span class="location">Lisbon</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<p class="next-date">
    Next date and location: 
</p>
```